# How to Debug C# code in visual studio code

Tags: c#, debugging, namespaces, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my c# code in vs code but when I run I encountered some errors .and it needs some references.so I add system.data.sqlclient but again it needs reference for SqlDataAdapter .please help me to solve this problem

```
    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SelectUserswith", sqlconn);
                sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                dt.Clear();
                sqlda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows!=null && dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["username"] != null && dt.Rows[0]["Depassword"].ToString() == textBox2.Text.Trim())
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    MenuFrm f1 = new MenuFrm();
                    f1.un = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                    f1.uID = dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
                    f1.username = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                    f1.Show();
                }
               else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error :

> file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/JAVAD/Documents/SampleVsCode/Program.cs'
>       severity: 'Error'
>       message: 'The type or namespace name 'SqlDataAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
>       at: '13,17'
>       source: ''
>
> file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/JAVAD/Documents/SampleVsCode/Program.cs'
>       severity: 'Error'
>       message: ''DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
>       at: '16,20'
>       source: ''

Software : 
[image: Software image]

Answer (score 1):

The using clause makes a reference to the namespace of the classes you are using. You also need to add a reference to the dll that the namespace is defined in.

in solution explorer there is a node under your project called Reference . Right click this ans choose Add from the menu. Find System.Data and include that.

If you refer to the MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

It tells you the namespace and dll you need.

Namespace:   `System.Data.SqlClient`

Assembly:  System.Data (in **System.Data.dll**)

Comment: I do not mean Visual studio I mean visual studio Code.it is another software of debugging C# code,I uploaded Software image above

Comment: @javad The principle is the same. The error message is telling you that System.Data is not referenced. You need to add that reference. If VS Code does this differently from VS, you should determine how VS Code does it. Sorry, but I have no knowledge of VS Code beyond the fact that it exists.

Comment: I Referenced using system.data.sqlclient and sqldataadaptor is not defined for it but sqlcommand is defined I edited the code in above box

Comment: Then it appears that the two classes that cause the errors are not available either in .NET Core or VS Code or both.